# <img> sizes attribute not able to override base image width/height

Tags: html, css

I have this image on my website and I'd like to add width/height as good practices to avoid CLS.

```html
<img
  src="/img/image@1x.jpg"
  alt="Test image"
  sizes="(max-width: 767px) 320px, 378px"
  srcset="/img/protect@2x.jpg 758w, /img/protect@3x.jpg 1138w"
>
```

This is what I did (added the @1x image dimensions as `width`/`height`).

```html
<img
  src="/img/image@1x.jpg"
  width="378"
  height="252"
  alt="Test image"
  sizes="(max-width: 767px) 320px, 378px"
  srcset="/img/protect@2x.jpg 758w, /img/protect@3x.jpg 1138w"
>
```

However, the image now remains the same size regardless of the browser width, as if `sizes` wasn't here, do I need extra CSS to make it work ?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and after a lot of tests and research, I ended moving the `width` and `height` attributes values to the CSS `aspect-ratio` property, directly inline in a `style` attribute.

In your example this would give:

```html
<img
    src="/img/image@1x.jpg"
    style="aspect-ratio: 378 / 252;"
    alt="Test image"
    sizes="(max-width: 767px) 320px, 378px"
    srcset="/img/protect@2x.jpg 758w, /img/protect@3x.jpg 1138w"
>
```

This respects the `sizes` attribute.

To negate CLS and remove the line "Image elements do not have explicit `width` and `height`" from the PageSpeed audit, you will have to set a `width` in CSS to all images in order to allow the browser deduce the `height` from the `width` (thanks to the specified `aspect-ratio`). I would recommend setting this as a default for all your img elements:

```css
img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

You can always set a new width to a specific image with a more specific selector like a class later on:

```css
.specific-image {
    width: 40px;
}
```

Note that it doesn't work with the `max-width` CSS property.